# In GWT, how can I override DisclosurePanel's CSS using <ui:style> or ClientBundle

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have a class that extends Composite and contains a DisclosurePanel at the top-level of the associated UiBinder file.

In DisclosurePanel, the HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="gwt-DisclosurePanel gwt-DisclosurePanel-closed>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="display: block;" class="header">
        <div class=""> <!-- an HTMLPanel I've shoved in to a <gwt:customHeader> block -->
           ...
        </div>
      </a>
...
```

In my UiBinder file I can use addStyleNames="{style.???}" and style some things, like I can style the DisclosurePanel itself and I can style my HTMLPanel inside the , but I can't style the

```
<a>
```

except by doing this:

```
disclosurePanel.getHeader().getParent().getElement().getStyle().setTextDecoration(TextDecoration.NONE);
disclosurePanel.getHeader().getParent().getElement().getStyle().setColor("black");
```

in the code, but that's ugly and the style is now in two places, the code and the UiBinder file.

The reason I'm doing that is to get rid of the underlining and blue color that the  has by default. Another alternative is to do something like this:

```
.gwt-DisclosurePanel a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text: black;
}
```

but then I would need to reference that CSS file from my home page (Client.html) or reference from the gwt.xml file, but both of those ways of doing things are deprecated.

How do I do this in a better way, or is it not possible?

Comment: So, all you want is applying CSS without using CSS, isn't it? What the reason of this very uncommon requirements?

Comment: All my widgets use UiBinder files with some css defined in a <ui:style> block. I wanted to be able to do the same thing with this widget to style the anchor element but it doesn't seem to be possible.

What do you mean I want to apply CSS without using CSS? I don't think I said that, so we must be misunderstanding each other.

Comment: Hmmm...will ensureInjected() do what I want? Can I just define a CssResource and a ClientBundle that references that CssResource and then call ensureInjected on the CssResource and it will inject all the CSS, even if I haven't referenced all the methods on my CssResource sub-interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hmmm...will ensureInjected() do what I
>   want? Can I just define a CssResource
>   and a ClientBundle that references
>   that CssResource and then call
>   ensureInjected on the CssResource and
>   it will inject all the CSS, even if I
>   haven't referenced all the methods on
>   my CssResource sub-interface?

Yes and no - you'd have to [disable CSS obfuscation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Levers_and_Knobs) (`<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty" />` - warning, that's global, so probably not what you want) in order for it to work. But if you reference those class names only from your UiBinder templates as such you should be fine:

```
<!-- Insert usual UiBinder stuff here -->
<ui:with field='res' type='com.example.client.resource.SomeCoolBundle'/>
<!-- SomeCoolBundle has a CssResource defined and available via style() -->

<div class='{res.style.lbox}'></div>
```

Just remember to mark the GWT classes as [`@external`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes) in your CSS file or else you won't be able to override them (since they'll get obfuscated):

```
@external .gwt-TextBox, .gwt-PasswordTextBox, .gwt-Button, .gwt-CheckBox;
```

If this doesn't suit your needs (or is to cumbersome), by all means *do* use one of those "deprecated" (not really) methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would declare my style in UIBinder, then add CssResource in my java code.

In UiBinder:

```
   <ui:style field="dPanelStyle" type="com.*.client.*.JavaFile.DisclosurePanelStyle">
        .main {
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-left:10px;
            width:492px;
        }
        .open {
        }
        .closed {
        }
        .header,
        .header a,
        .header td {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black; 
            cursor: pointer;
            cursor: hand;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color:#A2DCE8;
        }
        .content {
            border-left: 0px solid white;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }        
    </ui:style>

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:DisclosurePanel ui:field="dPanel" styleName="{dPanelStyle.main}">
        </g:DisclosurePanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

In JavaFile.java:

```
public interface DisclosurePanelStyle extends CssResource {
    String main();
    String header();
    String content();
}

@UiField DisclosurePanelStyle dPanelStyle;
@UiField DisclosurePanel dPanel ;

public JavaFile() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    dPanel.getHeader().setStyleName( dPanelStyle.header() );
    dPanel.getContent().setStyleName( dPanelStyle.content() );
}
```